# Update Legacy Java to use TLS 1.1/1.2

Tags: java, ssl

I have a legacy java (server) application that was built and runs on JRE 1.6.  I'm looking to update the system to use TLS 1.1/1.2.  These are supported in both Java 7 and 8.

The question is, do I only need to update the JRE the application runs on, or do I need to also rebuild the jar files with the appropriate version of the JDK?

I know that, generally, the JVM is backward compatible, but will the JDK 1.6 built jar file only support TLS 1.0, or will I get the benefits of the updated JRE without rebuilding?

Thanks.

Comment: Just try it. Should work.

Comment: I did some tests...  I wrote a simple program that displayed the supported protocols and the enabled protocols.  The hope was to move to Java 7 for the short term (Java 8 long term, but it breaks the test framework...).  Both Java 7 and 8 report that they support 1.1/1.2, with Java 8 (only) having it enabled.  I couldn't figure out how to get Java 7 to enable without code :(.  If I have to change code and redeploy, may as well put off until we can fix the test framework and rebuild/deploy on Java 8...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on nature of your application, if your application is using some class file level operation (asm, spring, etc..) with some third party libraries, those won't be forward compatible (i.e. application manipulating classes built on JDK 6 won't be compatible on JRE 8 without upgrade on library)

core classes would be runtime compatible but since 6 is too old and maintaining your code in 6 would not work longer, I would suggest you to compile it once with 8 fix the compilation error those you might get

and use it with runtime 8